# PHP: How to calculate person's age in months+days?

Tags: php, date

I want to calculate person's age in months plus days using date of birth (example: 1986-08-23).

For example:

```
0 months and 25 days old.
5 months and 20 days old.
150 months and 4 days old.
285 months and 30 days old.
```

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: What value do you start with ?

Comment: What's the input? Seconds, Minuts, Days, years+days? Hard to come up with an answer without enough info.

Comment: @alex: date of birth (example: 1986-08-23)

Comment: Sorry for less info in the beginning. Usually the input is date of birth when you have to calculate age.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('1990-10-13');
$diff = $date->diff(new DateTime());
printf("%d months and %d days old", $diff->y*12 + $diff->m, $diff->d);
```

Note that [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/datetime.diff) requires PHP 5.3.0 or higher.

Comment: Will this be accurate WRT leap years?